# Creating Columns Inside Loops In Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops, jupyter-notebook

I am running the following in which I am creating the new column named `NEW_DATE` inside the loop.
I want to for each row, the loop calculates an interval and then sums that interval to a `DATE` and the result is stored in `NEW_DATE`.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
    DATE        INFO
0   2021-01-22  0.375
1   2020-12-04  0.125
2   2021-01-01  0.500
3   2020-12-24  0.375
4   2020-12-10  0.125
```

The code is this:

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], format='%Y%m%d')

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    c1 = df['INFO'][index]
    print(c1)
    
    c3 = datetime.timedelta((1/c1)*5)
    print(c3)

    c2 = df['DATE'][index]
    print(c2)   
    
    df['NEW_DATE'][index] = c2 + c3
    print(df['NEW_DATE'][index], '\n')
```

At the moment I get the following error:
`KeyError: 'NEW_DATE'`

If I remove write `df['NEW_DATE'][index] = c2 + c3` the code runs but the values stored in `NEW_DATE` aren't correct as they are different from the ones printed.

How can I do what I described above? Am I on the right path?

Comment: It looks like you need to add the `NEW_DATE` column to your dataframe before trying to set values for each row.  You can search for "pandas add column to dataframe" for several ways to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick to that solution, first create the empty column befor the for loop, for example:

```
df['NEW_DATE'] = np.nan
# for loop ...
```

And to assign the value, you might want to use loc

```
df.loc[index, 'NEW_DATE'] = c2 + c3
```

Generally speaking, `itterrows()` is very slow, normally this type of problems should be addressed using vectorized methods:

```
df['NEW_DATE'] = df['DATE'] + pd.to_timedelta((1/df['INFO'])*5, unit='D')
```

Comment: I understand the vectorized method but when I run both methods, the `NEW_DATE` column values are right on the method with `itterrows()` and wrong on the vectorized method. Not sure why this happens. Like c3 has to be in days (not a date), not sure if in vectorized is summing days do c2. Do you know how it can be done in vectorized like that?

Comment: `datetime.timedelta` receives first argument as days, `pd.to_timedelta` uses by default nano seconds. check the edit using the argument `unit`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error, because the column does not exist. You need to create it before the loop

```
df['NEW_DATE'] = np.nan
```